# ssis package stopped tranfserring some fields

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, informix

I have an SSIS package that reads from an ODBC (Informix) table, and dumps that data into a table.
Both tables have the same structure, and neither had changed (no upgrades or structure changes).
In the past few days, the package is failing to enter the data into the SQL server, but is not producing any error message and the other fields are filled out correctly.
Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing that, or how to correct it?

Sample code from one of the queries that transfers the data:

> select 'select * from hvdn where row_date != TODAY and row_date > date(''' + convert(char(10),(select max(row_date) from DW.hvdn),101) + ''') ' as [HVDNSQL]

Control Flow:
[image: Control Flow picture]

Data Flow:
[image: Extraction Job]

Extraction Job is the only diagram under Data Flow.
There are no Parameters or Event handlers.
The queries that are built to extract the data either use `select * from <table_name> where date > last_date_extracted` or `select <almost_everything>,<aggregated field as more than 255 fields caused some issues> from <another_table>` with the same criteria.

All fields in the destination table match definition and size of the source table.

Comment: Are you by any chance using any Derived Column SSIS expressions that are configured with "Ignore failure"?

Comment: I wouldn't even know what a derived column expression is. The ssis string that creates the SQL for the odbc statement is `select 'select * from hvdn where row_date != TODAY and row_date > date(''' + convert(char(10),(select max(row_date) from DW.hvdn),101) + ''') ' as [HVDNSQL]`

Comment: Can you describe your SSIS package and development environment in greater detail? Are you using Business Intelligence Development Studio to edit the package, in which you've defined a task that instantiates a data input source and flows it to a data output source, possibly with some intermediate transformation nodes? That's the kind of usage of SSIS that I'm most familiar with.

Comment: @SeanCheshire FYI...a derived expression is an expression used within the `Derived Column` transformation component of your SSIS package.

Comment: When you say it's failing but fails to produce an error message, does that mean you just have a destination table with no rows?  Also, are you able to replicate the issue if you run the package in SSDT?

Comment: When the package is hanging out, doing nothing. What does the destination server show as activity? sp_whoisactive, XE, profiler, whatever tool you chose. Same goes for the source system, do you see any activity there that would prevent one of the queries to run? I assume you don't have logging turned on? If you don't, then you can fake it by adding the [/rep](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx) parameter on when you run the package (either via sql agent or command line) I'd try... EWID If this is from the command line, route to a file `> \temp\output.txt`

Comment: the data is not been transferred to a specific field. All other fields in the row get populated, but the one field does not have data. The data is available in the source table, and it will transfer correctly if I use excel to pull the data from the source, and then use SSIS in SQL Server to transfer the data from excel to the destination table.

Comment: Just remembered, on a couple of occasions I had mapped certain fields (from a source file, not a database table, incidentally) incorrectly to fields in the data output node (database table). I think I left the destinations of those fields as `<ignore>`, or some such text, and so they didn't get through. Can you check your mappings to make sure everything is mapped the way it should be?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue with 2005. My data flow was constructed much as yours is-many unrelated sources and destinations. For volume X, all the data arrived in the destination as expected. For volume X+1, all the rows arrived but it was as if the right half of data was sheared off. Opened a ticket with MS support. The resolutions was a hot fix + redesign of the data flow. Basically, break out what you have from 1 data flow to many data flows. They run in parallel, just not the same dataflow.

Comment: All fields are mapped correctly (no ignore)...   All data flows are in parallel. One SQL statement to one table. total of 8 sql statements and 8 unconnected dataflows. The package has related queries stacked one above the other for aesthetic purposes

Comment: I've now completely recreated the file (from scratch) omitting the data counts part of the package (informational only) and I still get the same error. Seems it's something to do with Informix to SQL Server character translation. Informix driver indicates Unicode (en_US.UTF8), SQLServer has field defined as NVARCHAR. They should be equivalent, but perhaps i am missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ODBC driver I was using got out of sync with the one one  the server.
I have no idea how this would affect the data extraction/load, but upgrading the driver to exactly the same one on the server allowed all the data to flow correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking through my old SSIS notes, and I came across something that looks like it *might* be of help to you. Here, let me quote myself verbatim:

> Ran into a bizarre case where SSIS dropped some source data, completely inexplicably, and merely running the package in the GUI (as opposed to the CLI) seemed to fix it; re-publishing the newly saved package also got the CLI run to succeed (i.e. not drop the data).

Just a shot in the dark.

(Here GUI refers to Business Intelligence Development Studio, and CLI refers to running the saved `.dtsx` package file via the `dtexec.exe` utility.)

Comment: I get the same effect whether I use the GUI or the command line

Comment: If that is the case put some data viewers on the data flow and observe the data - where is it NULL? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140318.aspx. Can you arrow the issue down to one data flow or is it in all of them?